# How to escape white space charachter in imap command line?

Tags: php, imap

My problem is that I want to login to yahoo imap server using my user/pass.
The problem is that my password contains a space charachter, so how do I escape it, i used '^]' but it did not work, this is the code:

```
$user = "example@yahoo.com";
$pass = "hey you!";
```

**Command:**

```
 mohsen LOGIN ".$user." ".$pass
```

it gives this error,
mohsen BAD [CLIENTBUG] Invalid command or arguments

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap them in quotes:

`A LOGIN "example@yahoo.com" "hey you!"`

You don't have a closing quote in your example.

Comment: That's it, love you buddy ;)

Comment: This will, of course, break when the user enters a password (or even a user name) which happens to contain the quote mark.

Answer (score 2):

Read RFC3501 and find out the syntax for passing strings around. Take a look at what options you have available (`atom`, `quoted-string`, `literal`) and what implications for escaping/formatting they bring.

Why don't you use some IMAP library given that you apparently do not know the pretty low-level building blocks which IMAP consists of?

Comment: Hey you gotta start somewhere